# Unity: Loading mp3 from StreamingAsset Folder in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load a MP3 from the streamingasset folder in a unity project running under IOS. In the editor everything works fine, but on the iPhone the MP3 is not loading.

I know about the filepath issues, but I assumed to have done everything correctly. Here is the code:

```
string fileName = "mytestfile";

if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
    path = "file:/" + System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName + ".mp3");
} else {
    path = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + fileName + ".mp3";
}
        
Debug.Log ("LOAD FROM STREAMING ASSET " + path);
                   
// Start a download of the given URL
WWW request = new WWW (path);
                    
// Wait for download to complete
yield return request;
    
// use request.audio 
AudioClip loadedMp3 = request.GetAudioClip (false, false);   
Debug.Log ("Result length " + loadedMp3.length);
```

And here is the output in xcode:

> LOAD FROM STREAMING ASSET file://var/mobile/Applications/{appid}/appname.app/Data/Raw/mytestfile.mp3
>
> Result length 0

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong? As I said, in the editor everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually know this because I was using it today. streaming assets in iOS is called /Raw/. So you have to do a #if UNITY_IPHONE and reference /Raw/ in lieu of StreamingAssets. In android it gets even more convoluted. You have to reference your .jar!! Aren't you glad you're using iOS?

Also you don't need file://

## if UNITY_EDITOR

Use StreamingAssets

XCode player build magically transforms your directory into Raw. Therefore during runtime your code must say this!